# Count transaction with "Max wait time reach" message in grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, telemetry

I am trying to count all transaction from logs with message "Max wait time reach" for that I am using following Lucene query
`host : sassacquirerselection* && message : Max wait* && paymentPlatform: $paymentPlatform && globalMerchantUID : $globalMerchantUID`
[output for query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeE0U.png)

[query in grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvoxA.png)
if there is any transaction from logs with such message it return count but if there are no message then it simply shows "No Data". I want it to return count as 0 if there is no transaction with message instead of "No Data".
I am trying to use this count in math expression to count % of transactions with response time below < given_time, but overall expression evaluates to "No data" because of this.

I am stuck on how to achieve this.